# TypeError : clean_country() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, django, forms, class, self

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    currency = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Currency_choices)
    continent = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Select_continent())   
    def clean_country(self):
        continent = self.cleaned_data['continent']
        result = Select_country(continent)
        return result 
    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=clean_country()) //error is here
```

i'm trying to get the selected field in Continent and display al countries in that continent
so try use clean_country which return a list fo countries in the selected continent.
but i had TypeError : clean_country() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
so how can i use this function?

Comment: You don't want to use it there at all. I think what you're trying to do is have a form that, when you fill in a specific value for "continent", will respond by filling in possible values for country. But you absolutely can't do that just on the server side in this manner. Perhaps you should add more explanation and context to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `AJAX` for a better way. You can check selected item with jQuery and send that data to your view. Then you can do `anything you need` with that.

If more explanation needed, say it please.